# Count number of registers in interval

Tags: python, sql, pandas, time-series

I think I'd better explain what I want to achieve through an example. Supposed I have this dataframe:

```
     time
0     2013-01-01 12:56:00
1     2013-01-01 12:00:12
2     2013-01-01 10:34:28
3     2013-01-01 09:34:54
4     2013-01-01 08:34:55
5     2013-01-01 16:35:19
6     2013-01-01 16:35:30
```

I would like to, given a interval T, count, for each line, how many registers were "opened" in that interval. For example, this would be the output, considering T = 2hours:

```
     time                  count
0     2013-01-01 12:56:00  1     # 12:56-2 = 10:56 -> 1 register between [10:56, 12:56)
1     2013-01-01 12:00:12  1 
2     2013-01-01 10:34:28  2     # 10:34:28-2 = 8:34:28 -> 2 registers between [8:34:28, 10:34:28) 
3     2013-01-01 09:34:54  1
4     2013-01-01 08:34:55  0
5     2013-01-01 16:35:19  0
6     2013-01-01 16:35:30  1
```

I wonder how to obtain this result using pandas. If I was considering just the dt.hour acessor, for T equals 1, for example, I could create a column count per hour, and than shift it by 1, summing the result of `count[i] + count[i-1]`. But I don't know if can generalize this for the desired ouput.

Comment: I don't understand how you're defining those intervals. How do you get `[10:56, 12:45]` for the 2 hours before 12:56, instead of `[10:56, 12:56)`?

Comment: And how does your proposed solution work? If you're counting by hour, that means 12:56 and 12:04 are going to end up in the same bucket, and you won't be able to distinguish between the 2 hours up to 12:56 and the 2 hours up to 12:04—they're both going to include the one opened at 10:34, even though that's only correct (I think) for the latter.

Comment: You're right, @abarnert. It just work to group rows by hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to mark all register opening times as +1 and all register closing times as -1.  Then sort by time and perform a cumulative sum over the +/- 1 values to get the count open at a given time.

```
# initialize interval start times as 1, end times as -1
start_times= df.assign(time=df['time'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=2), count=1)
all_times = start_times.append(df.assign(count=-1), ignore_index=True)

# sort by time and perform a cumulative sum get the count of overlaps at a given time
# (subtract 1 since you don't want to include the current value in the overlap)
all_times = all_times.sort_values(by='time')
all_times['count'] = all_times['count'].cumsum() - 1

# reassign to the original dataframe, keeping only the original times
df['count'] = all_times['count']
```

The resulting output:

```
                 time  count
0 2013-01-01 12:56:00      1
1 2013-01-01 12:00:12      1
2 2013-01-01 10:34:28      2
3 2013-01-01 09:34:54      1
4 2013-01-01 08:34:55      0
5 2013-01-01 16:35:19      0
6 2013-01-01 16:35:30      1
```

Comment: Brillant!  +1 very very nice.

Comment: I have to say that as I'm glad for your solution, I'm having trouble to understand the logic. Rs.

Comment: @pceccon:  oops, I switched the interval start/end logic in my old solution (thought 'time' as was interval start, but it's really the end).  Modified to correct this logic.